# very strange behaviour in Asterisk: Callee is Caller when agent from a queue responds

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I saw something strange in asterisk take a loot at the following extensions

```
[from-internal]
exten => 7000,1,Answer
same => n,queue(queuename,,,,60,,test)
same => n,Set(GLOBAL(APPELANT)=${CALLERID(num)})

[macro-test]
exten => s,1,Set(GLOBAL(APPELE)=${CALLERID(num)})
```

you will notice that APPELANT and APPELE don't have the same value
APPELANT will contain the caller when APPELE will contain the
callee how is it possible? is it a bug?

I got this from FreePbx 13 (asterisk 11 and above)

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not bug.

You queue members setuped via Local channel.

Can recommend you do following

1) NOT USE GLOBAL VARIABLES for channel staff

2) do Dumpchan at start of your macro and see in which variable you now have caller.